# How to know where this series converges uniformly and converges absolutely

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Im struggling a bit with absolutely convergence and uniformly convergence. The task is to determine where this series converge uniformly and absolutely.

$\sum_{k \geq 0} (\frac{1}{z-3})^k$

To determine where this converge absolutely I simply say that $|\frac{1}{z-3}| < 1$, but how do I determine where this converge uniformly? Would anyone like to give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

The series $\sum_k \zeta^{k}$ diverges for $|\zeta | >1$ and it converges for $|\zeta | <1$. It converges uniformly on compact subsets of the unit disk. An equivalent statement: It converges uniformly on $\{\zeta: |\zeta| \leq r\}$ for every $r <1$. Now put $\zeta=\frac  1{z-3}$.

Comment: Okey, I suspected it was something like that. Will it always converge on every compact subset inside the open disk where it converges absolutely, regardless what radius it absolutely converges for?

Comment: @zzz__ if $K$ is a compact subset of the u8n ti disk then $K \subseteq \{\zeta: |\zeta| \leq r\}$ for some $r <1$ so we get absolute and uniform convergence on $K$.